# (null) after using NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, nsdate, xcode4.5, nsdateformatter

I am trying to format a NSDate from a NSString:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, dd.MM.yyyy"];

NSString * appStart = [appointment start];
NSLog(@"app start: %@", appStart);
NSString *startDateFormatted = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:appStart];
NSLog(@"formatted date: %@", startDateFormatted );
```

Output:

```
2012-12-31 15:21:04.722 App[3296:907] app start: 2012-12-31 15:00:00
2012-12-31 15:21:04.723 App[3296:907] formatted date: (null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stringFromDate` takes a `NSDate`* as an argument and not `NSString`*. If you need further help with that let me know...

Comment: That is correct. Due to the fact that my data was a NSString, I had to convert it first to a NSDate in order to format it properly. Thank you!